# Android button setBackgroundDrawable method shows black

Tags: android, image, button, background

```
private void setupBitmaps()
{
    BitmapFactory.Options opts = new BitmapFactory.Options();

    opts.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;

    playImage = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.play, opts);
    pauseImage = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.pause, opts);
    selected = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.button_pressed, opts);   
    previousImage = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.previous, opts);
    nextImage = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.next, opts);
}

private Drawable scaleImage(Bitmap image, int newWidth, int newHeight)
{
    Bitmap scaledBitmap=Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(image, newWidth, newHeight, true);

    Drawable d = (new BitmapDrawable(scaledBitmap));

    return d;
}
```

I have a problem where when I start my Activity, the setBackgroundDrawable method doesn't work on the buttons. It just shows a black area over the button.

Now here's the weird part. I call the same method on the click listeners and the images appear. I did resize the images from the drawable folder so I don't know if that is the problem. I tried many ways to fix it and they didn't seem to work(they weren't huge fixes). 
The log cat does say something about it though:

```
05-06 09:51:25.489: W/OpenGLRenderer(22598): Unsupported bitmap config: 0
```

Comment: I've got a similar problem. Did you solve yours?

Comment: Yes I did. For me,  I used instead a Runnable that was calling the set Background Drawable method until the button was drawn.